# MongoDB - Update an Key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been trying to update an Object for this collection. Below is the collection. Looking for Server 3.6 version.

Here The ask is Need to update the class name from "HISTORY" to " HISTORY_NEW". Need to do, for some students in the class. Need a query that will select all student records in student collection with "HISTORY" class in it and update them to "HISTORY_NEW ". I have around 30,000 records and not getting a bulk update method.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611f90aa43f77a728879c395"),
    "studentId" : "stu1",
    "classes" : {
        "History"  : {
        "TeacherName" : "T1",
        "Marks" : [ 
            {
              "Internal": 15
            }
        ]
    },
        "Geography" : {
            "TeacherName" : "T2",
            "Marks" : [ 
                {
                    "Internal" : 20
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "updateDate" : ISODate("2021-10-12T11:40:47.156Z")
}
```

This is the result  I am expecting

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611f90aa43f77a728879c395"),
    "studentId" : "stu1",
    "classes" : {
        "HISTORY_NEW"  : {
        "TeacherName" : "T1",
        "Marks" : [ 
            {
              "Internal": 15
            }
        ]
    },
        "Geography" : {
            "TeacherName" : "T2",
            "Marks" : [ 
                {
                    "Internal" : 20
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "updateDate" : ISODate("2021-10-12T11:40:47.156Z")
}
```

.Or is that even possible with the kind of collection above or going via code route?

So far this is what I have, without any success.

Get all students' Ids and then update the Class name. But that is also not working and don't think it is smart to update DB 30,000 times.

```js
var studentIds =[];
db.studentSubject.find({"classes.History":{$exists:true}})
    .forEach(function(u) { studentIds.push(u.studentId) })


studentIds.forEach(function(studentId) {
    var result;

    try {

    result =db.studentSubject.updateOne(
        {studentId:studentId},
        { $set :  {"classes.History": "HISTORY_NEW",}},  
        { upsert: false}); 


    } catch (e) { 
        print(e);
    }

});
```

Comment: Your sample collection data was invalid for "Marks". Can you re-check and update it? Thanks.

Comment: Since you mention you want to update for **all students**, then you don't need to specify studentId, just update the document with `{"classes.History":{$exists:true}}`.

Comment: @YongShun,How about set method ? My set mothed is completly  resetting it ..

Comment: Hmmm, I think I misunderstand your question. Your desired result is to update the **key**? `"classes": { "HISTORY_NEW": {...}, ...}`? Or you attach your desired result in the  question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @YongShun  I want to update the key .I will update the  question as it can create confusion.I have updated question to get desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your scenario, you need [`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator.

As discussed in the comment, you don't need to fetch each document to get `studentId` and then pass it to update each document. Just bulk update by checking the document has `classes.History` field.

```
db.collection.update({
  "classes.History": {
    $exists: true
  }
},
{
  $rename: {
    "classes.History": "classes.HISTORY_NEW"
  }
},
{
  upsert: false,
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wXuataiKVUT)